# 403 forbidden in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have site built with Wordpress and it is live since yesterday. I noticed I can't see specific page, it is generated category for tagged posts. Only specific category has a problem, every other category works great.
I receive following error.

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /page_X/ on this server.
```

I already tried deleting htaccess file so Wordpress can recreate new one but it doesn't work. 
For example, `www.mydomain.com/pageX` should be visible

Htaccess is currently this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I tried something like this

```
<Limit GET POST>
 order allow,deny
 allow from all
</Limit>
```

Comment: No doubt just a typo, but you state `page_X` in the reported error, but `pageX` in the example. Is there anything different about this category? Unusual encoding? Funny characters?? This doesn't seem to be .htaccess/mod_rewrite related - that is the standard WordPress code.

Comment: Yeah, that was just an example, real page is in croatian language so I changed it. This is the real page, it doesnt have any strange characters. www.domainname.com/biljke

Comment: Maybe this is better suited to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ ?